# Cannot open image in pygame on android

Tags: python, pygame

I am programming  a mini game and I need to load some images but when I loaded images sone unexpected error raised can someone please help me to get out of it
Here is this code

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:pygame

import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
image = pygame.image.load("Audi.png").convert()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
         if ev.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

   clock.tick(60)
   surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
   surface.blit(label, (0, 0))
   pygame.display.flip()
```

And error which I am getting  is in this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image filepath has to be relative to the current working directory. The working directory is possibly different to the directory of the python file.

The name and path of the file can be get by [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-related-module-attributes). The current working directory can be get by [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html).

If the image is in the same folder as the python file, then you cab get the directory of the file and concatenate the image filename. e.g.:

```py
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os

# get the directory of this file
sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# [...]

image = pygame.image.load( os.path.join(sourceFileDir, "Audi.png") ).convert()
```