# How do I get the background image to upload?

Tags: python, pygame, background-image, typeerror

The program should fully cover the screen with the background image. instead, it says that it is a type error.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
```

> TypeError: argument 1 must be a sequence of length 2, not 1

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
size = [600.450]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("yy")

done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.image.load('calmingBG.jpg').convert()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    screen.blit(background,[0,0])
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is your size variable is set to the numeric value of 600.450. You should set the variable to [600, 450].

I would also recommend you to use the sys module when you quit the game loop. It would be something like this:

```
import sys
import pygame

# set variables

while not done:
    # game loop

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank you, the program runs now but it still won't display the image. it says: 
```background = pygame.image.load('calmingBG.jpg').convert()```
pygame.error: Couldn't open calmingBG.jpg

Comment: @Nneoma please be more specific about this error. Is calmingBG.jpg in your working directory? Is it spelled correctly? thanks.

Comment: @aqua959 *"Couldn't open calmingBG.jpg"*, read [Cannot open image in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57766969/cannot-open-image-in-pygame-on-android/57767162#57767162)